# Is it possible to use Scala jar library in _Android_ Java project?

Tags: java, android, scala, jar

Any "Use Scala on Android" tutorials I find only show to make a simple "Hello World" app. Has anyone actually succeeded in using a Scala library jar in a real life Android app?

I tried to use goose library (https://github.com/GravityLabs/goose/) in my Android project. I built goose-2.1.22.jar from the sources fine. Inserted it into libs directory of my Android project, and added some code to test what will happen:

```
String url = "http://www.cnn.com/2010/POLITICS/08/13/democrats.social.security/index.html";
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
Goose goose = new Goose(cfg);
com.gravity.goose.Article article = goose.extractContent(url);
String s = article.cleanedArticleText().toString();
```

The project compiled fine, no complains. When I try to run it though, I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.gravity.goose.Configuration
```

A little bit better after adding scala-for-android.jar to libs form "Scala for Android" project, or scala-library.jar from the latest stable Scala - then I get:

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.gravity.goose.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.scala:77)
    at com.hyperionics.ScalaTest.TestActivity$1.onClick(TestActivity.java:31)
```

Is there some trick to make it work?

---

**More information:** the crash is in Configuration.scala file of goose, on exactly this line:

```
var contentExtractor: ContentExtractor = StandardContentExtractor
```

I added *all* the jars from Scala distribution lib directory to my project after a period of testing, but there is no difference, same crash. Also found "Scala for Android" project at http://code.google.com/p/scalaforandroid/ and added it's jars instead of the ones from standard Scala distro, no difference. To compile my project and go around the error "Android Dex: Too meny methods ..." I had to use DexGuard, as with Proguard again I was getting weird errors.

Any more tips on how to make this work would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's certainly possible, as [this article](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala) and others can attest.

Comment: It would seem so, Robert, but the article is generic on Java + Scala mix. In my case it seems that I need to add more libraries to the project, but jars must be "dexed" for Android Dalvik VM, and I get an error "Android Dex: Too meny methods, 67771, max is 65536. The trick is to use Proguard to remove unnecessary methods before "dexing", but still have troubles with this.

Comment: The title of your question could be better.  Visitors arriving from Google will be expecting a philosophical discussion or tutorial, not this highly-specific troubleshooting question.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! My question is general enough: make any Scala library jar run with a regular Android app, written in Java. Searched for a long time and could not find any example, only tutorials how to write short "hello world" apps for Android totally in Scala. If I figure it out, I'll write a tutorial on how to do this.